# Implementing Normalization Inside Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization

I'm currently playing around with a basic LSTM-based Autoencoder using the Tensorflow library. The goal is for the Autoencoder to reconstruct multivariate time-series. I'm interested in moving the  feature-wise normalization of the data from the data pipeline to inside the model.

Currently I normalize data the following way:

```
normalizer = Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(data_train)
data_train = normalizer(data_train)

inputs = Input(shape=[None, n_inputs])
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed((Dense(n_inputs)))(x)
model = Model(inputs, x)
```

Which works as intended, leads to respectable loss (~1e-2) but is outside the model.
According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers) (under "Preprocessing data before the model or inside the model"), the following code should be equivalent to the above snippet, except that it runs inside the model:

```
normalizer = Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(data_train)

inputs = Input(shape=[None, n_inputs])
x = normalizer(inputs)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed((Dense(n_inputs)))(x)
model = Model(inputs, x)
```

However, running the latter variant leads to astronomical loss values (~1e3) and also worse results in testing. Hence my question is: what am I doing wrong? Could it be that I'm misunderstanding the documentation?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods seem to give consistent results as long as the normalizer is applied only to the inputs (i.e. to the feature matrix) when used outside the model:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Normalization
np.random.seed(42)

# define the input parameters
num_samples = 100
time_steps = 10
train_size = 0.8

# generate the data
X = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=5, size=(num_samples, time_steps, 1))
y = np.mean(X, axis=1) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(num_samples, 1))

# split the data
X_train, X_test = X[:np.int(train_size * X.shape[0]), :], X[np.int(train_size * X.shape[0]):, :]
y_train, y_test = y[:np.int(train_size * y.shape[0]), :], y[np.int(train_size * y.shape[0]):, :]

# normalize the inputs inside the model
normalizer = Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(X_train)

inputs = Input(shape=[None, 1])
x = normalizer(inputs)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed((Dense(1)))(x)
model = Model(inputs, x)

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=0)

print(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test))
# 10.704551696777344

# normalize the inputs outside the model
normalizer = Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(X_train)

X_train_normalized = normalizer(X_train)
X_test_normalized = normalizer(X_test)

inputs = Input(shape=[None, 1])
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed((Dense(1)))(x)
model = Model(inputs, x)

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train_normalized, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=0)

print(model.evaluate(X_test_normalized, y_test))
# 10.748750686645508
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can confirm that your methodology is reproducible. Given that the purpose of the autoencoder was to reproduce the inputs I assumed that I needed to normalize the target as well, which is where the discrepancy originated from.